# evaluate user defined function in gnuplot

Tags: input, gnuplot, user-defined-functions

Frequently, I end up having user-defined functions in gnuplot like the following:

```sh
a=1
b=1
y(x)=(-b+sqrt(b**2-4*a*(1-x)))/(2*a)
```

This allows me to easily plot `y(x)` and compare that with other data. But sometimes, I'd need to evaluate `y(x)` for a specific value (*e.g.* `y(1)`), but if I:

```sh
gnuplot> y(1)
         ^
         invalid command
```

My lame solution to this is to:

```sh
gnuplot> plot y(1)
Warning: empty y range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
```

This approach gives me the right answer in the first set of square brackets. But I'm sure there's a native solution to evaluate my user-defined function in gnuplot that I couldn't find.

So: Do you know any way to evaluate user-defined functions in gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `print`. If you want to format the number you will need to `print sprintf()`. Eg

```
print y(20)
print sprintf("%5.3f",y(20))
```